# Server random downtime windows server 2003 sp2 .net4

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0, windows-server-2003

Server Specks

Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition SP2

IIS 6

.net4

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU
X5680 @ 3.33GHz, 2.00GB of RAM
Physical Address Extension

I am having trouble finding the cause of our server's random downtime. Our clients inform us that their website goes down for hours at a time. Sometimes users are able to log in however the site is extremely slow/unstable and unusable. Sometimes users are not able to log in at all. When users are able to log in not all images are displayed (they get the image not found image).

We upgraded their website from .net1 to .net4 because we thought the cause of their downtime and random user log out was due to them running their website on .net1. The website was running fine with no issues for a few months.

The first time the server started to go down after that was due to the drive with which the website resided on running out of disk space. There was 40GB partitioned to this drive and 20GB was added. This didn't resolve the issue for very long.

The second time the server would randomly go down, I noticed in the Event viewer, that the web worker associated with the app pool used by the website would periodically require to be recylcled. That is, in the Security tab of the Event Viewer I would periodically see an event with ID 1074 reading 'A worker process with process id of '1540' serving application pool 'Net4' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.'. I then went into this app pool's properties and saw that the app pool would be recycled every 29 hours, which is the default. I modified this to have the app pool recycle every day at 3:00am. Since that we have not seen this event in the Event Viewer. We were able to catch the website during one of its downtimes before this was changed and recycled the app pool manually. This resolved the issue in this one instance.

This did not permanently fix the issue however, as we are still receiving emails from our client informing us that the website is down for hours at a time.

I then set up a performance monitor counter log. We have managed to monitor the server's performance during many of these downtimes. It does not appear to be a problem with memory as there is plenty of space on the drive. It does not appear to be a memory leak or related to excessive paging as there are no running processes which take up an excessive amount of % Processor Time and the Pages/Second Memory counter does not peak at an excessive amount during most of the downtime (I'll explain why excessive paging occurs later). The total IO Data Bytes/sec and IO Other Data Bytes/sec Process counter does not appear to be usually high or low during downtime. The total Thread Count and Handle Count Process counter do not exhibit any abnormal spikes or drops during this time. The total thread count, at a given time, seems to be between 600 and 900, give or take. The total handle count, at a given time, seems to be between 15,000 and 23,00, give or take. The % Time in Jit .NET CLR jit counter for instance w3wp is 0 for about half of the time and will randomly peak at almost 100 the other half, most of the time peaking for just a moment but rarely peaking for about 10 minutes, unrelated to downtime.

There are random times throughout the day where the process dsmcsvc takes up most, if not all, of the % Processor Time. This is a process run by the Symantec Antivirus software. When this process takes up the % Processor Time there is a corresponding event in the Event Viewer signifying that a new virus definition file has been uploaded that is, an Application event with ID 7 'New virus definition file loaded. Version: #version number#'. When this event occurs, the Pages/Sec counter spikes. Sometimes it spikes to only 200-300 but will at times peak over 10,000. This event seems to be completely unrelated to website downtime. I have researched the Symantec Antivirus software and found that there is a known memory leak in old versions of this software. I have found that this software is known to cause high memory usage when the link to a process called NavLogon.exe is broken/does not exist. This process does not appear to exist on the server so I currently have no way of restoring the link to it. I also found that this software uses Crypt32.dll and that old versions of Crypt32.dll have a known memory leak. The Crypt32.dll which exists on the server was last updated in 2007.

The Performance Monitor log monitors the total Sessions Active ASP.Net Applications counter. During downtime, the total number of sessions does not exhibit any abnormal behavior, there are a normal amount of active sessions during this time. Active sessions at a given time can be between 0 and 200. I was informed that the time when the most users are active is during 1st shift, however during about 10pm and 2am every day, this number peaks.

The site runs JavaScript client side, and Visual Basic.net server side. All users have about 10-15 session variables almost all of the time.

When the site goes down there are no events which seem to correspond to its downtime in the Event Viewer.

I also have set up a W3C Extended Log File Format log for this site. During downtime there seems be an excessive amount of GET requests for a Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx.

I have seriously run out of ideas at this point and have extensively searched the web for solutions and come up empty. Any feedback as to why this may be occurring would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> It does not appear to be a problem with memory as there is plenty of space on the drive.

Really? Memory and hard drive space are two completely different things. 2GB of RAM was okay a decade ago, when that server was new, but today it's laughably small.

But don't bother upgrading or adding RAM. This server is old enough, the problem is probably just that the hardware is reaching the end of it's useful life. Additionally, the operating system is also nearing it's end of life. Server 2003 is scheduled for end of life on July 14, 2015. After that date, there will be no new patches of any kind produced for Server 2003... not even critical security patches. That will make Server 2003 completely unsuitable as a web server.

This seems like a good time to execute a transition to a completely new server.

Comment: Sorry to have mistaken drive space and memory. The website will be disbanded after June 2015. " the problem is probably just that the hardware is reaching the end of it's useful life". I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this. Besides transitioning to a new server, are there any other options you can suggest, are there any reasons you can think of which would cause this?

Comment: Hardware just gets old. It could be a failing memory stick, weakening hard drive motor or power supply, bad or weak capacitor on the motherboard, bad sectors developing on the hard drive, failing cpu, weak of failing cooling fan, or a number of other things. With hardware that old, it's best not to even try to fix it, because as soon as one item is fixed, another starts to give you trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I believe this is somehow tied to the RadUploadProgressHandler control. As I said before I set up an iis log to log requests and it seems that during downtime the only requests which are logged are GET requests for a Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx, with a requests for a webpage occurring every couple minutes or so. Since this is machine has one single core CPU it can in reality only process one task at any given time. So if the server is continuously processing these GET requests then it can't process any other requests and would appear to be down, correct?

Comment: Not exactly. A single CPU can only execute one thread at a time, but it can have many active threads and processes, and the operating system will schedule time for each of them.

Comment: I see. This makes sense since, what I observed from my performance log, all processes appeared to run during downtime as they normally would. However, each website has its own process associated with it. If that process is stuck processing these GET requests, then it has no time to process any other requests? I've discovered that this is actually a known issue with this control and telerik has provided a work around http://www.telerik.com/forums/repeated-calls-to-repeated-calls-to-raduploadprogresshandler-ashx-after-ajax-call